# Not understanding makefile

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile

I'm struggling with this Makefile. It bombs out on the last line. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone see it? Thanks!

```
CC           = gcc
CFLAGSFUSE   = `pkg-config fuse --cflags`
LLIBSFUSE    = `pkg-config fuse --libs`

CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra

encfs: encfs.o log.o xattr_new.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LLIBSFUSE)   

xattr_new: xattr_new.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@

encfs.o: encfs.c log.h params.h xattr_new.c
    gcc -g -Wall `pkg-config fuse --cflags` -c pa4-encfs.c

log.o : log.c log.h params.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGSFUSE) log.c

xattr_new.o: xattr_new.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation
> 0 has invalid symbol index 11
>
> /usr/bin/ld:/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation
> 1 has invalid symbol index 12
>
> /usr/bin/ld:/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation
> 2 has invalid symbol index 2
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation
> 3 has invalid symbol index 2
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation
> 4 has invalid symbol index 11
>
> ...

Comment: Do you have `main` in `xattr_new` and `pa4-encfs`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your makefile per se.  The problem is with the link, it looks like.  In addition to the error messages it would be useful if you showed the link command which precedes the error messages.  One interesting thing here is that this seems to be a 32bit link: are you sure the libraries you're linking with are 32bit as well?

Comment: Someone else posted a solution to this, but has since deleted it. What I did was changed xattr_new: xattrnew.o to $(CC) $(CFLAGS) xattr_new.c   This seems to have solved it. At a minimum, I'm not getting any compiler warnings or errors. I haven't fully tested things out just yet. If you don't think that this will work, please advise. Thank you!